# Recode from a long list of variables

Tags: r

Using the example dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(KY27SCH1 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, NA, 5, 2, 4, 4, NA, 4, 
                                  5, 3, 5, 5), KY27SCH2 = c(5, 4, 4, 4, NA, 4, 1, 4, 4, NA, 4, 
                                                            5, 4, 5, 5), KY27SCH3 = c(4, 4, 5, 4, NA, 4, 4, 4, 5, NA, 5, 
                                                                                      5, 3, 5, 5), KY27SCH4 = c(3, 5, 5, 4, NA, 5, 4, 5, 5, NA, 5, 
                                                                                                                5, 4, 5, 5)), .Names = c("KY27SCH1", "KY27SCH2", "KY27SCH3", 
                                                                                                                                         "KY27SCH4"), row.names = 197:211, class = "data.frame")
```

I apply a line of code to add the four different columns together before binding this new column to the original dataframe:

```
KC27sc_R <- rowSums(df[, c("KY27SCH1", "KY27SCH2", "KY27SCH3", "KY27SCH4")], na.rm = TRUE)
df <- cbind(df, KC27sc_R) # Adds columns to survey dataframe
```

I then want to recode variable KC27sc_R using the table of results detailed below:

```
5= -4.287
6 = -3.040
7 = -2.405
8 = -1.960
9 = -1.605
10 = -1.296
11 = -1.011
12 = -0.735
13 = -0.456
14 = -0.168
15 = 0.134
16 = 0.454
17 = 0.796
18 = 1.166
19 = 1.574
20 = 2.035
21 = 2.582
22 = 3.299 
23 = 4.594
```

i.e. 5 in column KC27sc_R would become -4.287.

Is there a way of recoding a column from a list of numbers without having to go through each number in turn?  I normally use the recode function but I am unsure how to do this with a large list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear because you seem to ask one thing, but show sample code for doing something else. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Many thanks @Ananda Mahto, I have now taken out the confusing code.

Comment: How do I use cut @hadley when my intervals are not even?

Comment: If you plot those values against each other they make a perfectly smooth curve. Instead of a look-up table, I would create a (cubic?) function that maps any value onto its new value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume we have put your lookup table as a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
mydf <- structure(list(V1 = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
    16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23), V2 = c(-4.287, -3.04, -2.405, 
    -1.96, -1.605, -1.296, -1.011, -0.735, -0.456, -0.168, 0.134, 
    0.454, 0.796, 1.166, 1.574, 2.035, 2.582, 3.299, 4.594)), .Names = c("V1", 
    "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
mydf
#    V1     V2
# 1   5 -4.287
# 2   6 -3.040
# 3   7 -2.405
# 4   8 -1.960
# 5   9 -1.605
# 6  10 -1.296
# 7  11 -1.011
# 8  12 -0.735
# 9  13 -0.456
# 10 14 -0.168
# 11 15  0.134
# 12 16  0.454
# 13 17  0.796
# 14 18  1.166
# 15 19  1.574
# 16 20  2.035
# 17 21  2.582
# 18 22  3.299
# 19 23  4.594
```

You should be able to just use something like the following to get what you are looking for:

```
df$RECODED <- mydf$V2[match(as.character(df$KC27sc_R), as.character(mydf$V1))]
df
#     KY27SCH1 KY27SCH2 KY27SCH3 KY27SCH4 KC27sc_R RECODED
# 197        4        5        4        3       16   0.454
# 198        4        4        4        5       17   0.796
# 199        4        4        5        5       18   1.166
# 200        4        4        4        4       16   0.454
# 201       NA       NA       NA       NA        0      NA
# 202        5        4        4        5       18   1.166
# 203        2        1        4        4       11  -1.011
# 204        4        4        4        5       17   0.796
# 205        4        4        5        5       18   1.166
# 206       NA       NA       NA       NA        0      NA
# 207        4        4        5        5       18   1.166
# 208        5        5        5        5       20   2.035
# 209        3        4        3        4       14  -0.168
# 210        5        5        5        5       20   2.035
# 211        5        5        5        5       20   2.035
```

The `as.character` part in there is to help mitigate potential FP problems.

---

This is very similar conceptually to the `merge` solution that has been provided, but is likely to be much faster.

Benchmarking on an artificial dataset:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(0:25, 100000, replace = TRUE), ncol = 2))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  A = {
    df2 <- merge(df, mydf, by.x="X1", by.y="V1", sort = FALSE)
  },
  B = {
    df3 <- cbind(df, recoded = mydf$V2[match(as.character(df$X1), 
                                             as.character(mydf$V1))])
  }
)
Unit: milliseconds
#  expr       min        lq    median       uq       max neval
#     A 141.32530 149.61354 154.99230 162.7845 239.26242   100
#     B  24.93267  25.32541  25.73723  26.0792  96.44209   100
```

The basic matching approach is well over 5x as fast as `merge`. Additionally, `merge` tends to do funky things with your row ordering. Compare the first few rows of the original dataset (`df`), with those of the merged one (`df2`), and my solution (`df3`). As you can see, `merge` has totally rearranged the `data.frame`, even though we had specified "`sort = FALSE`".

```
head(df)
#   X1 X2
# 1  6 15
# 2  9 18
# 3 14  8
# 4 23  3
# 5  5 22
# 6 23  1
head(df2)
#   X1 X2    V2
# 1  6 15 -3.04
# 2  6 23 -3.04
# 3  6  3 -3.04
# 4  6  0 -3.04
# 5  6 20 -3.04
# 6  6 16 -3.04
head(df3)
#   X1 X2 recoded
# 1  6 15  -3.040
# 2  9 18  -1.605
# 3 14  8  -0.168
# 4 23  3   4.594
# 5  5 22  -4.287
# 6 23  1   4.594
```

Comment: "tends to do funky things" is really an understatement. I like the wording in `?merge`: "for sort = FALSE [the rows] are in an unspecified order". Not 'unsorted' in relation to the original data, but sorted in an 'unspecific way'?...Great match solution and thanks for the timings, +1!

Answer (score 3):

If you keep your recoding values in a second data frame, you may try `merge`:

```
# original data
df <- data.frame(x = sample(5:7, 10, replace = TRUE))

# recoding data
df2 <- data.frame(x = 5:7, new_x = c(-4.287, -3.040, -2.405))

merge(df, df2)
```

**Edit following @hadley's comment**

The solution above is testing floating point numbers for equality, which is it not a reliable method, see [R FAQ 7.31 Why doesn't R think these numbers are equal?](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). One way to handle this is to set the columns used for merging to class "`integer`". (I note that this potential issue is not considered in the last example in `?merge`)

```
# original data
df <- data.frame(x = as.integer(sample(5:7, 10, replace = TRUE)))

# recoding data
df2 <- data.frame(x = as.integer(5:7), new_x = c(-4.287, -3.040, -2.405))

merge(df, df2)
```

**Edit following @Ananda Mahto's comment - funky sorting with merge and handling of NA**

```
# original data with NA
df <- data.frame(x = as.integer(c(7, NA, 5, 6, NA, 5)))

# recoding data as above, without NA
merge(df, df2, sort = FALSE)
# 'unspecified' order and no match with NA

# can at least handle NA by including NA also in recoding data
df2 <- data.frame(x = as.integer(c(5:7, NA)), new_x = c(-4.287, -3.040, -2.405, NA))
merge(df, df2, sort = FALSE)
```

**A possible merge-oid solution: `join`in `plyr` package**
    "Unlike `merge`, `join` **preserves the order** of x no matter what join type is used", and no need for NA in recoding data.

```
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(x = as.integer(c(7, NA, 5, 6, NA, 5)))
df2 <- data.frame(x = as.integer(c(5:7)), new_x = c(-4.287, -3.040, -2.405))
join(df, df2)
# looks OK
```

From `?join`: "`Join` is often faster than `merge`". Whether this is the case here, and whether it is faster than `match`, I leave for someone else to show.

Comment: That might be a bit dangerous with FP numbers.

Comment: @Henrik, +1 for following through on addressing the problems identified!

Answer (score 1):

I am not hundred per cent sure I got your question right. But I think what you ask is: you have a mapping from an integer to a value and you want to replace all integers in a data frame (or vector) by the value specified in the mapping.

I would put the mapping in a list:

```
code = list()
code[[5 ]] = -4.287
code[[6 ]] = -3.040
code[[7 ]] = -2.405
code[[8 ]] = -1.960
code[[9 ]] = -1.605
code[[10]] = -1.296
code[[11]] = -1.011
code[[12]] = -0.735
code[[13]] = -0.456
code[[14]] = -0.168
code[[15]] = 0.134
code[[16]] = 0.454
code[[17]] = 0.796
code[[18]] = 1.166
code[[19]] = 1.574
code[[20]] = 2.035
code[[21]] = 2.582
code[[22]] = 3.299 
code[[23]] = 4.594
```

And then use apply (or sapply for vector) to do the replacement:

```
apply(df, c(1,2), function(x) code[[x]])
```

Comment: Many thanks @f3lix - if I have one specific column within my dataframe to apply your 'code' function to i.e. KC27sc_R in my example above... how do I add this to the code?

Comment: You could do: `df$KC27sc_R = lapply(df$KC27sc_R in, function(x) code[[x]])` In your example you will run into a problem with the 0 in df$KC27sc_R; to avoid this you can use code[[x+1]] instead and change the lookup list (code) accordingly...

Comment: Yeah, I would use a list for this, too, but construct it like `code <- list(\`0\` = NA,\`5\` = -4.287,\`6\` = -3.040,...)` to avoid error-inviting repetition. (This also uses chars instead of integers, like Ananda's solution.)

Answer (score 1):

I like @Henrik's `merge` solution, it seems clear and easy to use.

I went the way of using `factor`, although I don't think the process of converting back to numeric is ever very elegant.  @hadley's solution using `cut` is similar.

```
df = data.frame(x = sample(5:7, 10, replace = TRUE))
# Using factor(), to convert to numeric have to go through a character
df$y = as.numeric(as.character(factor(df$x, labels = c(-4.287, -3.040, -2.405))))

# Using cut() is similar to factor, need to use the breaks argument
df$z = as.numeric(as.character(cut(df$x, breaks = 3, labels = c(-4.287, -3.040, -2.405))))
```

Answer (score 1):

An answer that requires a minimum of typing and is portable:

```
# Your original values
origval = seq(5,23)
newval = c(-4.287, -3.04, -2.405, -1.96, -1.605, -1.296, -1.011, -0.735, -0.456, -0.168, 0.134, 0.454, 0.796, 1.166, 1.574, 2.035, 2.582, 3.299, 4.594)

# generate a relationship
sp = smooth.spline(origval,newval)

# look up a value based on your original sequence
pval = predict(sp, origval)
```

Now `pval$y` will contain the predicted (converted) points.

You can put any other set of values into the `predict` function in place of `origval`, in any order, even ones that weren't in the data series (5.5, etc)

Applied to your data set, you can create a placeholder for your variable and then "predict" its values:

```
df$KY_Rnew = df$KC27sc_R
df$KY_Rnew[!is.na(df$KY_Rnew)] = predict(sp,df$KY_Rnew[!is.na(df$KY_Rnew)])$y
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your mapping values are all integers, you could create a vector containing the coded values at the position of the mapping values:

```
# using mydf defined by Ananda Mahto:
mydf <- structure(list(V1 = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23), V2 = c(-4.287, -3.04, -2.405, 
 -1.96, -1.605, -1.296, -1.011, -0.735, -0.456, -0.168, 0.134, 
 0.454, 0.796, 1.166, 1.574, 2.035, 2.582, 3.299, 4.594)), .Names = c("V1", 
 "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))

# create vector with index positions corresponding to objective values:
vmap <- rep(NA, length=max(mydf$V1)) 
vmap[mydf$V1] <- mydf$V2

vmap
# [1]     NA     NA     NA     NA -4.287 -3.040 -2.405 -1.960 -1.605 -1.296
# [11] -1.011 -0.735 -0.456 -0.168  0.134  0.454  0.796  1.166  1.574  2.035
# [21]  2.582  3.299  4.594

# Assign NA to zero values in KC27sc_R (as you cannot have a zero position in a R vector)
# (this could also be another value defined in mydf if you want zero to map to something)
KC27sc_R[KC27sc_R==0] <- NA

# Then, select the values in vmap using the indices defined in KC27sc_R:
Krecode <- vmap[KC27sc_R]
data.frame(KC27sc_R, Krecode)


# KC27sc_R Krecode
# 197       16   0.454
# 198       17   0.796
# 199       18   1.166
# 200       16   0.454
# 201       NA      NA
# 202       18   1.166
# ... etc
```

This should be fairly fast with a long list as all operations are vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, let's suppose that your table of results is stored in a matrix `yo`:

```
yo <- matrix(0, nrow = 19, ncol = 2)
yo[, 1] <- c(5:23)
yo[, 2] <- c( -4.287, -3.040, -2.405, -1.960, -1.605, -1.296, -1.011, -0.735, -0.456, -0.168, 0.134, 0.454, 0.796, 1.166, 1.574, 2.035, 2.582, 3.299, 4.594)
```

i.e., the first column of `yo` corresponds to values you want to be changed, the second - what you are changing with. Put simply, treat `yo` as a function - first column is this function's ***x*** variable, second is the function's output.

The first thing you need to figure out is the index of values of KC27sc_R are actually present in `yo[, 1]` (in which rows you can actually substitute old values with the new ones). This is done like so:

```
ind <- which( df$KC27sc_R %in% yo[,1] )
```

`ind` gives you the rows of all the values of KC27sc_R you can change. The next step would be to get all these values:

```
a <- df[ind,]$KC27sc_R
```

The final step is to link the values in `a` with those in `yo[, 1]` - literally find rows of `yo[, 1]` where you can find each of the corresponding values in `a` - function `match` would be helpful here:

```
b <- match( a, yo[,1] )
```

Like `ind`, `b` is an index - for each value in `a`, it tells you which row of `yo[, 2]` you need to go to to find the replacement for this value in `a`. Final step is to replace values in your `df`:

```
df[ind, "KC27sc_R"] <- yo[b, 2]
```

That will do the trick.